# User create script from CSV file

Tags: bash, scripts

How to Create a shell script user_create.sh to parse a csv file and create user accounts. Default permissions of each user account should be readable - writable - executable for the owner, readable - executable by group
members, and no access allow for others. The CSV file is comma delimited, with the following columns:

- Real name
- Username
- Default password (required to be changed at the first login)
- Group name

Cron job that  records disk usage of each user  on the system  at  11:59pm every day, and  append these records to a log file  `/var/log/storage.log`.

Below is what I have now but for some reason it wont work.

Below is what I have now but for some reason it wont work.

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=data.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read accountname username password groupname
do
useradd -p $password -g groupname -c $accountname -s /bin/sh $username
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Here is one part of my cvs file:

```
AMELIA SMITH,asmith,AeMga7du,seniormanagement
OLIVIA JOHNSON,ojohnson,AhBob0e0,helpdesk
EMILY WILLIAMS,ewilliams,Ees3uiW0,products
AVA BROWN,abrown,rooyie8G,R&D
ISLA JONES,ijones,aeN6bohp,operations
JESSICA MILLER,jmiller,Eiqu3voh,R&D
POPPY DAVIS,pdavis,Eed3teiv,R&D
ISABELLA GARCIA,igarcia,eeNgi30h,sales
```

Comment: Why did you remove your script, that could help us find out what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: And please avoid screenshots. They can't be used as input data in sample scripts.

Comment: Please post actual text instead of screenshots.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

From what I saw in your own script, for the purpose of creating users, something like this will work for you:

- Remember

  - Group name should not contains whitespace
  - You simply can't use `-p password`, the password should be encrypted first.

*script.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash

file="data"

IFS=","

while read name user pass group
do

getent group $group >/dev/null || groupadd $group   

useradd -m -g $group $user -s /bin/bash

chpasswd <<< "$user:$pass"

# force user to change his/her password after login
passwd -e $user

done < "$file"
```

to monitor disk space, I suggest something like this in `/etc/crontab` file:

```
59 23 * * * root bash -c "echo ----; date; du -hd1 /home;" >> /var/log/storage.log
```

Comment: One shouldn't pass passwords or password hashes as command-line arguments. You can use `chpasswd <<< "$user:$pass"` after user account creation instead. You can also silence the output of `getent` with `>&-`. Otherwise good answer. +1

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I updated the answer ;) is there any reason for the first one? can't find out what's the different with `chpasswd`.

Comment: The difference is that with `chpasswd` the password is supplied via standard input which other users cannot inspect as opposed to the command-line of `passwd` (or any process) if they happen to look at the right moment (or have a program look for them). :-) If you look through your process list you'll notice that the command-line of processes owned by root are plainly visible to regular users.